# SOAP send xml string

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a webservice in PHP, using SOAP and one of sending parameters is 'fileContent' with is a string with xml content like this:

```
$string='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rootTag><a>tag</a></rootTag>';
```

The request is

```
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ws:fileContent>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rootTag><a>tag</a>  </rootTag>'</ws:fileContent>
  </ws:ReservationDetailsRQ>
```

The response is

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Bad Request</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can you tell how can i do this?

Comment: Consider embedding as CDATA.  Really, sending XML with SOAP is weird, why not just post the XML directly?

Comment: I am the server part and i expect to receive a string which is an xml. I test my webservice in SOAPUI. If i send any string without xml tag inside works

Comment: The SOAP request is just plain invalid so the server gives the correct response. So the only answer I could give would be: Yes, the response is correct - but that would not be very helpful. Instead consider to make clear in your question which response you expected instead and (very important) why you would expect a different response. Also it's important that you provide reference to your reservervation service. Which one are you using? Where is the documentation of it?